# Generate table(angular) from XML DataSet(ado.net)

Tags: angular, .net-core, syncfusion

The client sends a sql query that will be executed on the server. Server processes sql, retrieves data, and returns them as DataSet back to client side. They come in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiDataSet>
   \r\n
   <Table>
      \r\n
      <OperatorId>112051</OperatorId>
      \r\n
      <UserName>112051</UserName>
      \r\n
      <Name>Vasya  Whitebear</Name>
      \r\n
      <IsLeftHanded>false</IsLeftHanded>
      \r\n
      <PinCode>CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA</PinCode>
      \r\n
      <OperatorType>SystemUser</OperatorType>
      \r\n
   </Table>
   \r\n
   <Table>
      \r\n
      <OperatorId>114178</OperatorId>
      \r\n
      <UserName>114178</UserName>
      \r\n
      <Name>QaLab03Dev owner  QaLab03Dev</Name>
      \r\n
      <IsLeftHanded>false</IsLeftHanded>
      \r\n
      <PinCode>CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA</PinCode>
      \r\n
      <OperatorType>SystemUser</OperatorType>
      \r\n
   </Table>
</FlexiDataSet>
```

> It is important to note that the data will not always get in this form
>   because the client can execute any sql query. How to display this xml
>   as a table in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

First of all, you need Angular Library to [convert XML data to JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-xml2json).

> Component

```
public XML_DataSet = 'XML from question';
public tableHeaders = [];
public tableValues = [];

     ngOnInit() {
        this.PrepareData();
      }

      PrepareData() {
        let x = this.XML_DataSet;
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const xml = parser.parseFromString(x, 'text/xml');
        let json = this.xml2json.xmlToJson(xml); // XML is converted in JSON
        this.tableValues = json['FlexiDataSet']['Table'];
    
        for (let data of this.tableValues) {
          // Extract table headers
          this.tableHeaders = Object.keys(data);
          //Remove #text - unnecessary column
          this.tableHeaders.shift();
          break;
        }
      }
```

> HTML

```
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">
            {{header}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of tableValues">
          <td *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders">
            {{data[header]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

> CSS

To stylize your table you can use the tutorial on the next [link](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/stylish-css-tables-tutorial/).

[image]

> If you want to display results in the Angular Grid, change the HTML

```
  <div>
    <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="tableValues">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of tableHeaders" [matColumnDef]="column">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[column] }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableHeaders"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableHeaders;"></mat-row>
    </table>
  </div>
```

[image]

> If you want to display results in the Syncfusion EJ2 Grid, change the logic
>
> HTML

```
<div>
  <ejs-grid #grid [dataSource]='tableValues'
            height="100%"
            width='100%'
            [toolbar]='toolbar'
            [searchSettings]='searchOptions'
            [allowFiltering]=true
            [filterSettings]='filterSettings'
            [allowSorting]=true
            [allowPaging]=true
            [pageSettings]='pageSettings'
            [allowGrouping]=true>
  </ejs-grid>
</div>
```

> Component

```
  import { SearchSettingsModel, GridComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids';
  @ViewChild('grid')
  public grid: GridComponent;

  public grid: GridComponent;
  public toolbar: Object[] = ['Search'];
  public searchOptions: SearchSettingsModel = { fields: this.tableHeaders, operator: 'contains', ignoreCase: true };
  public filterSettings: Object = { type: "Menu" };
  public pageSettings: Object = { enableQueryString: true, pageSize: 20 };

SyncFusionGrid() {
    let columns = [];
    for (let data of this.tableHeaders) {
      let column = { field: data, headerText: data };
      columns.push(column);
    }
    this.grid.columns = columns;

    // Set column width
    for (let column of this.grid.columns) {
      column['width'] = '200';
    }
  }
```

Call SyncFusionGrid() method when we have data we need to show. In my example, this is the end of the method PrepareData()

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have done almost steps to achieve your requirement. The final step is you need to create EJ2 Angular using the following getting started link and bind the converted(XML data to JSON) data source to Grid. Please refer below documentation and sample links.

Getting Started: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started/

Local datasource binding: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/data-binding/?no-cache=1#local-data

Sample browser: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/grid/default